# Can the SQLite3 Command line be invoked from a python program?

Tags: python, sqlite, command-line

Is there any way of gaining addressability to the SQLite3 command line interface programmatically from within a script? I would like to write a program that builds a CSV file from a layer attribute table and then imports the CSV file to a database table.

I was thinking that something like this might work:

```
    import sqlite3
    conn = sqlite3.connect('qgis.db')
    curs = conn.cursor()

    commands = '''
    DROP Table video IF EXISTS
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS video(id, name, duration)
    .mode csv
    .import media.csv video
    .mode column
    .header on
    SELECT * from video
    '''

    curs.execute(commands)

    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
```

Comment: why do you need to invoke the command line? Why not just call the sqlite functions directly?

Comment: @BryanOakley There are no SQLite functions for the shell's dot commands.

Comment: Python can run programs. (And has its own CSV reader.)

Comment: I will take a look at the CSV module.  I am new to Python and was not aware that such a module existed. Does it have functions that match the dot-commands, such as import?  I attempted to issue a dot-command programmatically and Python complained that it was an invalid command.